# Conda issue with environment

Tags: python, macos, conda, miniconda

Thank you for the help but I am unable to download some packages. Packages like Numpy, Pandas are all good but I need the following for a project:

1. bowtie2
2. SRA tools
3. bedtools

When I tried to download it I get the following error: "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:"

This is my laptop: MacBook Air M2 2022
And I am using miniconda. I have just downloaded it so there should be no issues and I am working in the following environment:

```
 active environment : CHIP
active env location : /Users/frivetti/miniconda3/envs/CHIP
        shell level : 2
   user config file : /Users/frivetti/.condarc
populated config files : /Users/frivetti/.condarc
conda version : 24.1.0
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 3.11.5.final.0
solver : libmamba (default)
virtual packages : __archspec=1=m2
__conda=24.1.0=0
__osx=13.4=0
__unix=0=0
base environment : /Users/frivetti/miniconda3 (writable)
conda av data dir : /Users/frivetti/miniconda3/etc/conda
conda av metadata url : None
channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64
https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
package cache : /Users/frivetti/miniconda3/pkgs
/Users/frivetti/.conda/pkgs
envs directories : /Users/frivetti/miniconda3/envs
/Users/frivetti/.conda/envs
platform : osx-arm64
user-agent : conda/24.1.0 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.5 Darwin/22.5.0 OSX/13.4 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/23.12.0 libmambapy/1.5.3
UID:GID : 501:20
netrc file : None
offline mode : False
```

Thank you a lot

I added Bioconda, I even tried with other channels but none of it works. I have no idea what to do, I am very confused. I tried to download them in a hundred ways.

Comment: See duplicate. Bioconda does not directly support **osx-arm64** yet - you need to emulate. Also, `conda-forge` must be the priority channel (not `bioconda`). If you are just getting started and you are primarily a bioinformatician, I would recommend uninstalling Miniconda and replace it with [a Miniforge installation](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge), using the **osx-64** version so that emulation and Conda Forge will be the default.